# Update table data if there is a required document with the required value

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I work with the MySql database, I have a table "registry" there, for example, the document '78946123852' with the transaction sold "TransactionID" = 1 I want to update the lines "PercentSub" and "PercentAge" if I add the same document number but with a return transaction " TransactionID "= 2. I made a request but it does not work please help

```
UPDATE registry SET
registry.PercentAge=t2.PercentAge,
registry.PercentSub=t2.PercentSub
FROM registry AS t2
LEFT JOIN registry ON t2.NumberDocument=registry.NumberDocument AND t2.TransactionID='1' AND registry.TransactionID='2'
WHERE registry.NumberDocument='78946123852'
```

Error in MySql
[image]

I tried this update works in SQL Server 2008 but in MySQL it does not work

Comment: mysql and sqlserver are very different - you cannot run sqlserver code in mysql without amendment (except in the simplest of cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can principally rearrange order of `SET` Clause within the statement, and using subqueries like this

```
UPDATE registry AS r1 
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM registry WHERE TransactionID = 1 ) AS r2
    ON r2.NumberDocument = r1.NumberDocument             
   SET r1.PercentAge = r2.PercentAge, r1.PercentSub = r2.PercentSub 
 WHERE r1.NumberDocument = 78946123852
   AND r1.TransactionID = 2
```

*where the quotes of numeric values are removed presuming the data types of the related columns within the table are numeric.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=434649d8d1c9c40b71be42e66af8a92b)</kbd>

Comment: checked your script but Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'r1.TransactionID' in 'where clause'

Comment: oh yes @ariana , just a typo that I left by mistake within the subquery.

Comment: Barbaros Özhan, thank you my brother you helped me

Comment: Barbaros Özhan, how to correctly form this problem in the title or did I write it correctly?

Comment: @ariana , Perhaps, it might be `Update Within a Table Due to a Column With Matching Value For Different Rows`